# OPENROWSET SSMS to import excel file

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I am trying to use the OPENROWSET command in sql server management studio to query excel files.

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
                    'Excel 12.0;Database=P:\location of file.xlsx,
                    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

but I get the following message : Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" has not been registered.

I have installed the 64 bit version of https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 but I am still having no luck. My version of Office and SSMS are both 64 bit.

I can't work out how to get this to work, any help would be massivley appreciated.

Comment: I have had issues with Excel and 64 bit, I usually use 32 bit version and it works better.  Also are you using correct version of Excel?  Have you looked into using SSIS?  That works way better for this kind of thing.

Comment: Are you trying to do a one-time import or recurring schedule?  If only once, you could try exporting the Excel data to CSV. SSMS import is really easy with CSV.

Comment: @Brad, trouble is I cant use 32 bit excel as this is on my office computer and it only has 64 bit. I have tried using Excel 12.0, 14.0, 15.0 and 16.0 and I am getting the same message for all of them. What is SSIS?

Comment: @tgolisch, I just need to import the file once into a temp table, in the meantime the csv method may have to do, can you use openrowset with a csv file?

Comment: I haven't used openrowset directly.  I usually start with the import wizard (from SSMS) and modify the SSIS package that it generates, when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Register the Office Engine with SQL Server**

Here's the code I would use to register the Access/Office Engine with SQL Server. Otherwise SQL will not recognize it--even though it's installed on the Windows Server.

```
exec sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;

RECONFIGURE;

GO

exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;

RECONFIGURE;

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 

GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 

GO
```